# how to get the elementid of a kendo datepicker in a jquery each loop

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, each

Let's say I have several INPUTs all having class='dp' and element ids (dp1, dp2, dp3, etc)

```
    <INPUT id="dp1" class='dp' />
    <INPUT id="dp2" class='dp' />
    <INPUT id="dp3" class='dp' />
```

and these are being turned into kendo DatePickers:

```
$(".dp").kendoDatePicker( {....
```

and later we want to visit each of them in turn:

```
$(".dp").each( function (index, value) {


        });
```

Inside the `.each` block, how to get the `elementid` of the INPUT that underlies the current kendo DataPicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kendoui takes the classnames of the `input` and adds them to the wrapper element that it creates, so if you have 3 inputs elements with the `dp` classname, after generating the `kendoDatePicker` on these 3 - you will now have 6 elements in your DOM that has the `dp` classname.

What you can do is take only the `input.dp` elements

```
$('input.dp').each(...)
```

or take the `.dp` elements that doesn't have the `k-widget` classname in them

```
$(".dp:not(.k-widget)").each( ... )
```

Here is a working snippet (using the second way):

```js
$(".dp").kendoDatePicker();
$(".dp:not(.k-widget)").each( function (index, value) {
 alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<INPUT id="dp1" class='dp' />
<INPUT id="dp2" class='dp' />
<INPUT id="dp3" class='dp' />
```

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful info.

Answer (score 0):

you can get elements id like below

```
$(".dp").each( function (index, value) {
    var eleid = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

**Or by using Kendo api**

```
$(".dp").each( function (index, value) {
    var kele = $(value).kendoDateTimePicker().data();
    var keleid = kele.handler.element.context.id
});
```